# Find the sum of the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^{k+3}}{3^{k}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, geometric-series

Find the sum of the series $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^{k+3}}{3^{k}}$$

I imagine we are needing to use the geometric series approach (since that's the section I'm studying) but not sure how to get started with an exponent in the numerator and denominator...

Answer (score 1):

Write $$\frac{2^{k+3}}{3^k}=8\times \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k$$ and think at a geometric series.

Comment: Sorry to ask what may just be a simple algebra question, but how did you factor out 8 from the series?

Comment: It is $$2^{k+3}=2^k\times 2^3 =8\times 2^k$$ by the power rule.

Comment: Thank you! hat's a big help

Comment: Nice, that i could help you!

Answer (score 1):

$$ \begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^{k+3}}{3^{k}} & =  8 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac23\right)^k \\ 
 & = 8 \times {\frac {1}{1 - \frac23 }}  \quad\quad \text { Using the sum of Infinte G.P}\\ 
&= 8 \times \frac 3{1} =\color{blue}{\boxed{24}}\end{align}$$

[Sum of Infinite G.P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series)